# Environment variable export not working when entrypoint is used?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I have a base image that calls a `.sh` script which does an export of an environment variable. It looks something like this:

startup.sh:

```
source $(dirname "$0")/../scripts/export-file-based-secrets.sh
```

export-file-based-secrets.sh:

```
export SOME_VAR=bla
```

This is working fine:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/cafapi/opensuse-base:2.4.0
```

Built it:

```
docker build -t test .
```

Run it, passing the `env` command to docker so we can see the env vars. You can see that the  `DATABASE_PASSWORD` has been exported successfully:

```
docker container run -it --rm -e DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE=/temp/password.txt -e USE_FILE_BASED_SECRETS=true -v /mnt/d/temp:/temp test env
[15:58:16.256Z #008.??? INFO  -            -   ] startup.sh: Running export-file-based-secrets.sh...
[15:58:16.268Z #00F.??? INFO  -            -   ] export-file-based-secrets.sh: Reading DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE (/temp/password.txt)...
[15:58:16.278Z #018.??? INFO  -            -   ] export-file-based-secrets.sh: Successfully exported environment variable DATABASE_PASSWORD
...
DATABASE_PASSWORD=bla
```

However, if I change the Dockerfile to specify an entrypoint:

```
FROM docker.io/cafapi/opensuse-base:2.4.0
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c" , "/startup/startup.sh && env"]
```

Built it:

```
docker build -t test .
```

And run it, you can see the `DATABASE_PASSWORD` env var has no longer been exported (there is the `DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE` env var present, but this also should have been `unset` by `export-file-based-secrets.sh`):

```
docker container run -it --rm -e DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE=/temp/password.txt -e USE_FILE_BASED_SECRETS=true -v /mnt/d/temp:/temp test
[16:01:45.666Z #007.??? INFO  -            -   ] startup.sh: Running export-file-based-secrets.sh...
[16:01:45.678Z #00E.??? INFO  -            -   ] export-file-based-secrets.sh: Reading HISTORY_STATS_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE (/temp/password.txt)...
[16:01:45.687Z #017.??? INFO  -            -   ] export-file-based-secrets.sh: Successfully exported environment variable HISTORY_STATS_DATABASE_PASSWORD
...
DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE=/temp/password.txt
```

Note, I know I can use `-e DATABASE_PASSWORD=bla` to set the env var in the image, but for my use case I'd like to pass a password file instead, that my base image reads and then exports `DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE=/temp/password.txt`.

Does anyone know why this stops working once I specify an entrypoint, and how I can make it work?

Comment: Make it `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c" , ". /startup/startup.sh && env"]` -- `.` being the POSIX-standardized (and thus `sh`-compatible) name for `source`. If you don't source a shell that exports an environment variable, that variable is lost when the shell exits; and `./startup/startup.sh`, like every other script invoked as an executable, has its own interpreter when you don't source it, so the variable goes away when that interpreter exits.

Comment: Better still, end the `startup.sh` script with the line `exec "$@"`; make the image's entrypoint be only `ENTRYPOINT ["/startup/startup.sh"]` (must be JSON-array format, without the explicit `sh -c`), and then make the `CMD` be what you actually want to run (`CMD my-application`).  That would let you substitute in other commands when you start the container (`docker run --rm the-image /usr/bin/env`), and it would get launched at the end of the startup script.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas why `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c" , ". /startup/startup.sh && env && sleep 300"]` will display the env var that I exported, but when I `docker exec .. bash` into the container, I don't see the env var?

Comment: "when I docker exec .. bash into the container, I don't see the env var?" - is this because `docker exec ... bash` is a different env to the one that exported the env var (i.e. the entrypoint)?